# SQL query to update table only if all values for column match

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm playing around with queries and tables and have a table that looks like this.

```
Name   |      Job     | Status
===============================
Test1  |  Completed   | Pending
Test1  |  50%         | Pending
Test2  |  Completed   | Pending
Test2  |  Completed   | Pending
Test2  |  Completed   | Pending
```

Is there a query I can use that will look at the name and job column, and if the job column is "completed" for all matching names, update the status column to say "completed"?

To clarify, in the above example, all the "Test2" jobs are marked as completed, so I would like the status to also say completed - but only if ALL the Test2 jobs say completed.

Comment: What database are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one possible solution for SQL Server:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
SET Status = 'Completed'
WHERE
    Job = 'Completed' AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name AND
                      (t2.Job <> 'Completed' OR t2.Job IS NULL));
```

Comment: I think [a null value in Job may cause trouble](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cf55217a5581190471fe05bed4c03668)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson [I fixed it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2507a144a59f3f6a7e098bf86cb93bea), thanks.  I didn't consider that the job column might be `NULL`, but maybe it could be.

Answer (score 3):

Another option;

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Status = 'Completed' WHERE Name IN (
  SELECT Name 
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY Name
  HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN Job='Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
)
```

The inner select finds the names with all Job values set to Completed, and the update just updates Status of the rows with the found names.

[A DBfiddle for testing](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9578d29038cb0d1d3ccc83add0852252).

Comment: I would prefer: `HAVING MAX(Job) = 'Completed' AND MIN(Job) = MAX(Job)`, because then we could use an index, but +1 to an otherwise good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UPDATE Table_Name SET Status = 'Completed' WHERE Name = 'Completed' AND Job = 'Completed'
```

Comment: Thanks but this will just update all the jobs as completed. It should only update the status if ALL the jobs are marked as completed for each name.

Answer (score 1):

Please try it.

```
UPDATE yourTable  
SET Status = 'Completed'
WHERE
    Job = 'Completed' AND
     Name not in (select Name from yourTable where Job<>'Completed')
```

Comment: This is basically a copy of my answer and would even probably be optimized to the exact same query plan.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
create table #temp (Name varchar(20), Job varchar(20), sStatus varchar(20))

insert into #temp values 
('Test1'  ,  'Completed'   , 'Pending'),
('Test1'  ,  '50%'         , 'Pending'),
('Test2'  ,  'Completed'   , 'Pending'),
('Test2'  ,  'Completed'   , 'Pending'),
('Test2'  ,  'Completed'   , 'Pending')

update #temp set sStatus = 'Completed'
where Name not in (
    select a.Name from #temp a
    where a.Job <> 'Completed'
)

select * from #temp
```